# What is the meaning of "in some time"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.guru99.com/java-inheritance-polymorphism.html

**Please be patient. The Video will load in some time. If you still face issue viewing video click here**

What is the meaning of "*in some time*" in the above text. I guess that phrase means "*after a while*" but I am not sure.

Comment: "After a while" is correct. In others words the video won't play instantaneously, but only after some delay.

Comment: "In some time" is not idiomatic English in that context. I guess the message was written by somebody whose first language was not English.

Comment: Amplifying what @ColinFine said, the entire message is unidiomatic. "If you still face issue...." is not right and not how a native English speaker would write.

Comment: Well, how would a native English speaker write that message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In some time" is more definite than "in a while," implying your video will load in a definite (and hopefully short) period of time.

"In a while" is fairly ambiguous, and suggest the writer doesn't know just how long it will take.